# Python login through text file

Tags: python, authentication

I have some code that makes a login system that retrieves the accounts from a text file. The account format goes like this: Username:Password:ID, (1 is admin anything else is guest)
my current list:

```
Admin:Admin!:1
Guest:Password:0
test:test:0
```

but for some strange reason if I write in the admin credentials it lets me in but anything else fails here is my code:

```
import sys

username = raw_input("Username: ")
password = raw_input("Password: ")

createLogin = file("login.txt", "a")

with open("login.txt", "r") as login:
    lines = login.readlines()

while True:
    for line in lines:
        if line.split(":")[0] == username and line.split(":")[1] == password:
            print("Welcome back %s" % (username))
            while True:
                message = raw_input("")
        else:
            sys.exit()
```

I would appreciate it if someone could modify or tell me what to add to the code. Thanks.

Comment: because your `else` will run after checking the admin creds, and exit. You should use a flag that is checked after the for loop

Comment: What do you mean by "Flag"? try and except?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your issue is that you check the first line of the 'login.txt' file, and exit if it doesn't match. You could do something like this:

```
for line in lines:
    if line.split(":")[0] == username and line.split(":")[1] == password:
        print("Welcome back %s" % (username))
        while True:
            message = raw_input("")
else:
    sys.exit()
```

By moving the else one indent back, you create a [for/else](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/for_-_else.html) loop, which will run the `else` code if no lines in the file matched.

Comment: @ZerefDragneel no worries, happy to help! Please mark it as answered if it solved the issue :)

Comment: It says I need to wait 6 minutes to do it. I shall do it when it lets me :)